# Is initialization with default and copy ctors perfectly equivalent?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Consider the following simplest example:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
};

A a; //1

A b = A(); //2

int main(){ }
```

What is the difference between `//1` and `//2` unless 1 is being proceed by trivial default ctor, but 2 by trivial copy-ctor. I'm interested in memory layout, is it going to be differ in those cases?

Comment: Actually `a` is declared, but never initialized.

Comment: @Cyber And...? Don't see how it's releated to my question.

Comment: Well I thought you were implying that one of the constructors would be called for `a`, otherwise I'm not sure why you even included that line. For example `b`, only the copy constructor *would* be called [but actually the copy is elided](http://cpp.sh/9feb).

Comment: @Cyber: No, it's defined to be default initialised (after being zero initialised, since it's global).

Comment: what if there is no copy-ctor?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: #2 does not invoke the copy constructor. `A b = A();` is just extra syntax sugar, it is really invoking `A b;` instead, thus invoking the default constructor, same as #1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You mean copy-elision? Well, assume we compiled with flags pereventing that.

Comment: They should certainly be memory-layout equivalent. And due to both being global, should be content-equivalent as well. However, if *not* global, //2 will value-initialize, //1 will *not*. The elided copy not withstanding, that is a significant difference. Shove both in `main` and `a.a` will be indeterminate; `b.a` is going to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

If both constructors, and the destructor, are trivial, as here, then both are equivalent by the "as if" rule. (Although, if they were local variables, there would be a difference: the second specifies value-initialisation to zero rather than default-initialisation to an indeterminate value).

If they are non-trivial, then both are equivalent if the compiler applies copy elision - this is one situation, initialising an object from a temporary, where that optimisation is allowed.

In any case, the memory layout of the variable will be the same. `//2` will create, value-initialise, copy, and destroy a temporary if the copy isn't elided.

Comment: I do not understand your point about default-initialization. He is asking about construction versus construction-and-assignment. How does `1` versus `2` result in different initialization of the struct members?

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji There's no assignment going on in the second case. It's called copy-initialization. If `a` and `b` were local variables, `a` would be default-constructed. Since its constructor is trivial, `a.a` will have an indeterminate value while `b` (being copy-initialized from a value-initialized temporary) will have `b.a` equal to `0`. But in the OP's code since they are both in global scope they are zero-initialized and thus have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

> Is initialization with default and copy ctors perfectly equivalent?

**No.**

The language defines these kinds of initialization differently. However, in your specific example, modulo a single copy construction, the resulting semantics are identical.

---

> I'm interested in memory layout, is it going to be differ in those cases?

**No.**

Memory layout *must* be independent of initialisation method, otherwise it would impossible for a function defined in one translation unit to understand any object defined in another translation unit.

Every `T` in your program will have the same memory layout. In fact, every `T` produced by every compiler following the same ABI as yours will have the same memory layout.

This is quite deliberate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for correcting my now deleted answer. Question: doesn't the standard govern memory structure of objects to remain backwards compatibility with C? For example, PODs and arrays are contiguous in-memory and their sizes can be precisely calculated. Also, why does `A b = A();` call the copy constructor and not the assignment operator? Is this another weird grammar gotcha that loves to hide in C++?

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji: The ABI chosen for use by your platform and compiler govern memory structure of objects, and it's for compatibility with other executables and libraries on your computer, not for compatibility with C. And `A b = A()` is copy initialisation, invoking the copy constructor to create `b`. Nothing to do with `op=`. It's equivalent to `A b((A());`

Answer (score 1):

They are the same on my system:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A() { a = 7;}
};

int main(){
    A a; //1

    A b = A(); //2

}
```

gives

```
310         A a; //1
00401b49:   lea 0xc(%esp),%eax
00401b4d:   mov %eax,%ecx
00401b4f:   call 0x403cd8 <A::A()>
312         A b = A(); //2
00401b54:   lea 0x8(%esp),%eax
00401b58:   mov %eax,%ecx
00401b5a:   call 0x403cd8 <A::A()>
```